# Some questions are greyed out on Meta

Tags: support, user-interface

I'm seeing some greyed out questions on Meta.

[image]

Is this a normal behavior?  Or is something off with my system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are ignoring one (or more) of the questions tags, just hover over the tags to see which one(s).